# Subscribe a single observable inside another single creation rxswift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, observers, subscribe

I want to get data from server and update my DB after that I'll show received data to the user. For this goal I have a method(`getData()`) in my view model that returns a `Single` I call and subscribe this method in the view controller(`myVC.getData.subscribe({single in ...})`) in this method at first I call and subscribe(#1)(`getUnread()->Single`) the method run but I can not get the single event, I can not understand why I can't get the event(#3) in call back(#4)

after that I want to save data with calling(#2)(save([Moddel])->single)

```
//I removed some part of this code it was to big
//This method is View Model
func getData() -> Single<[Model]> {
    return Single<[Model]>.create {[weak self] single in
        //#1
        self!.restRepo.getUnread().subscribe({ [weak self] event in
            //#4
            switch event {
            case .success(let response):
                let models = response
                //#2
                self!.dbRepo.save(issues!).subscribe({ event in
                    switch event {
                    case .success(let response):
                        let models = response
                        single(.success(models))
                    case .error(let error):
                        single(.error(error))
                    }
                }).disposed(by: self!.disposeBag)
            case .error(let error):
                single(.error(error))
            }
        }).disposed(by: self!.disposeBag)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

.
.

```
 //I removed some part of this code it was to big
 //This method is in RestRepo class
 func getUnread() -> Single<[Model]> {
    
    return Single<[Model]>.create { single in
        let urlComponent = ApiHelper.instance.dolphinURLComponents(for: ApiHelper.ISSUES_PATH)
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlComponent.url!)

        ApiHelper.instance.alamofire.request(urlRequest).intercept().responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            switch statusCode {
            case 200:
                do {
                    let models = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: response.data!)
                    //#3
                    single(.success(models))
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            case 304:
                debugPrint(response)
            default:
                single(.error(IssueResponseStatusCodeError(code: statusCode ?? 0)))
            }
        }
    return Disposables.create()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to change your thinking. *You* don't do anything in the app. At best, you lay out the Observable chains (which don't *do* anything anymore than water pipes "do" something.) Then you start the app and let the "water" flow.

So with that in mind, let's examine your question:

> I want to get data from server...

It's not that "you" want to get the data. The request is made as a result of some action (probably a button tap) by the user or by some other side effect. What action is that? That needs to be expressed in the code. For the following I will assume it's a button tap. That means you should have:

```
class Example: UIViewController {
    var button: UIButton!
    var restRepo: RestRepo!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let serverResponse = button.rx.tap
            .flatMapLatest { [restRepo] in
                restRepo!.getUnread()
                    .map { Result<[Model], Error>.success($0) }
                    .catchError { .just(Result<[Model], Error>.failure($0)) }
            }
            .share(replay: 1)
    }
}

protocol RestRepo {
    func getUnread() -> Observable<[Model]>
}

struct ProductionRestRepo: RestRepo {
    func getUnread() -> Observable<[Model]> {
        let urlComponent = ApiHelper.instance.dolphinURLComponents(for: ApiHelper.ISSUES_PATH)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlComponent.url!)
        return URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: urlRequest)
            .map { try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: $0) }
    }
}

class ApiHelper {
    static let ISSUES_PATH = ""
    static let instance = ApiHelper()

    func dolphinURLComponents(for: String) -> URLComponents { fatalError() }
}

struct Model: Decodable { }
```

The thing to notice here is that `getUnread()` is an effect that is caused by `button.rx.tap`. The above establishes a cause-effect chain.

Your question goes on to say "you" want to:

> ... update my DB...

Here, the cause is the network request and the effect is the DB save so we simply need to add this to the viewDidLoad (note that the code below uses RxEnumKit.):

```
let dbResponse = serverResponse
    .capture(case: Result.success)
    .flatMapLatest { [dbRepo] models in
        dbRepo!.save(models)
            .map { Result<Void, Error>.success(()) }
            .catchError { .just(Result<Void, Error>.failure($0)) }
    }
```

Your question also says that "you" want to:

> ... show received data to the user.

Note here that showing the received data to the user has nothing to do with the DB save. They are two independent operations that can be done in parallel.

Showing the received data to the user has the serverResponse as the cause, and the showing as the effect.

```
serverResponse
    .capture(case: Result.success)
    .subscribe(onNext: { models in
        print("display the data to the user.", models)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Lastly, you don't mention it, but you also have to handle the errors:

So add this to the viewDidLoad as well:

```
Observable.merge(serverResponse.capture(case: Result.failure), dbResponse.capture(case: Result.failure))
    .subscribe(onNext: { error in
        print("an error occured:", error)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

---

The code below is all of the above as a single block. This compiles fine...

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import EnumKit
import RxEnumKit

extension Result: CaseAccessible { }

class Example: UIViewController {
    var button: UIButton!
    var restRepo: RestRepo!
    var dbRepo: DBRepo!
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let serverResponse = button.rx.tap
            .flatMapLatest { [restRepo] in
                restRepo!.getUnread()
                    .map { Result<[Model], Error>.success($0) }
                    .catchError { .just(Result<[Model], Error>.failure($0)) }
            }
            .share(replay: 1)

        let dbResponse = serverResponse
            .capture(case: Result.success)
            .flatMapLatest { [dbRepo] models in
                dbRepo!.save(models)
                    .map { Result<Void, Error>.success(()) }
                    .catchError { .just(Result<Void, Error>.failure($0)) }
            }

        serverResponse
            .capture(case: Result.success)
            .subscribe(onNext: { models in
                print("display the data to the user.", models)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        Observable.merge(serverResponse.capture(case: Result.failure), dbResponse.capture(case: Result.failure))
            .subscribe(onNext: { error in
                print("an error occured:", error)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

protocol RestRepo {
    func getUnread() -> Observable<[Model]>
}

protocol DBRepo {
    func save(_ models: [Model]) -> Observable<Void>
}

struct ProductionRestRepo: RestRepo {
    func getUnread() -> Observable<[Model]> {
        let urlComponent = ApiHelper.instance.dolphinURLComponents(for: ApiHelper.ISSUES_PATH)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlComponent.url!)
        return URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: urlRequest)
            .map { try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: $0) }
    }
}

class ApiHelper {
    static let ISSUES_PATH = ""
    static let instance = ApiHelper()

    func dolphinURLComponents(for: String) -> URLComponents { fatalError() }
}

struct Model: Decodable { }
```

I hope all this helps you, or at least generates more questions.